# Copy CSV link from Github and combine it with plots codes led error

Tags: javascript, html, vega-lite

I am **trying to create a map using Vega-Lite**.

Then I **tried to create a map about the rainfall and city in year 2019**. However, it does not display any map in the webpage at all. This is my first webpage design, I'm not sure where and how can I debug the error.  Anyone knows **in which part do I make a mistake?**

---

After debug the error said so:
**WARN Loading failed https://github.com/.....csv {}, why this happen? Can't I just copy the CSV link on Github?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console), when you open your file in browser.
You will get "WARN", "Loading failed", "data/us-10m.json"

I didn't find current file at your repo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My_First_Webpage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.16.1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.16.8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.12.2"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      /* Add space between Vega-Embed links  */
      .vega-actions a {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Vega-Lite Visualization</h1>
    <!-- Container for the visualization -->
    <div id="vis"></div>

    <script>
      // Assign the specification to a local variable vlSpec.
      var vlSpec = {
          "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
          "width": 500,
          "height": 300,
          "layer": [
              {
                  "data": {
                      "url": "data/us-10m.json",
                      "format": {
                          "type": "topojson",
                           "feature": "states"
                           }
                        },
                        "projection": {
                           "type": "albersUsa"
                       },
                        "mark": {
                           "type": "geoshape",
                           "fill": "lightgray",
                           "stroke": "white"
                        }
                    },
                   { 
                      "data": {
                         "url": "https://github.com/BocongZhao823/My_First_Webpage-/blob/main/rainfall_tidy.csv"
                       },
                      "projection": {
                           "type": "albersUsa"
                       },
                         "mark": "circle",
                         "encoding": {
                               "longitude": {
                                  "field": "longitude",
                                    "type": "quantitative"
                                },
                               "latitude": {
                                    "field": "latitude",
                                    "type": "quantitative"
                                },
                              "size": {"value": 10},
                             "color": {"value": "steelblue"}
                           }
                       }
                 ]
            };

      // Embed the visualization in the container with id `vis`
      vegaEmbed('#vis', vlSpec);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```